# Parsing html page with scripts

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing

I need to parse an `html` page inside of my application to retrieve data. Currently I use `HtmlAgilityPack` for this. But the page is dynamic, it contains scripts so it can't be parsed correctly. Is there a way to run scripts and somehow retrieve the final html output?

I'm thinking about a browser engine but without the visualization part.

Comment: When last I did something similar, I created a web browser control (windows forms) in my code and had it navigate to the pages in the website that I wanted based on values that I was looking for. This could also work for you as long as the scripts the page needs to run aren't responding to user input

Comment: since you mention HtmlAgilityPack, you might want to tag it C#